# How do I print a field from a pipe-separated file?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, awk, ksh

I have a file with fields separated by pipe characters and I want to print only the second field.  This attempt fails:

```
$ cat file | awk -F| '{print $2}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
bash: {print $2}: command not found
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key point here is that the pipe character (`|`) must be escaped to the shell. Use "`\|`" or "`'|'`" to protect it from shell interpertation and allow it to be passed to `awk` on the command line.

---

Reading the comments I see that the original poster presents a simplified version of the original problem which involved filtering `file` before selecting and printing the fields. A pass through `grep` was used and the result piped into awk for field selection. That accounts for the wholly unnecessary `cat file` that appears in the question (it replaces the `grep <pattern> file`).

Fine, that will work. However, awk is largely a pattern matching tool on its own, and can be trusted to find and work on the matching lines without needing to invoke `grep`. Use something like:

```
awk -F\| '/<pattern>/{print $2;}{next;}' file
```

The `/<pattern>/` bit tells `awk` to perform the action that follows on lines that match `<pattern>`.

The lost-looking `{next;}` is a default action skipping to the next line in the input. It does not seem to be necessary, but I have this habit from long ago...

Answer (score 21):

Or just use one command:

```
cut -d '|' -f FIELDNUMBER
```

Comment: Note that the crux of the problem is the pipe character, not the command used.  But this is a fine solution.

Comment: I thought about it, but I'd rather have an answer that explains the problem.  That's kinda the point of my comment, in fact. ;-)

Comment: Would be `cut -d '|' -f FIELDNUMBER FILENAME`

Answer (score 4):

The pipe character needs to be escaped so that the shell doesn't interpret it.  A simple solution:

```
$ awk -F\| '{print $2}' file
```

Another choice would be to quote the character:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

And 'file' contains no pipe symbols, so it prints nothing.  You should either use 'cat file' or simply list the file after the awk program.

Comment: Urg.  Sorry about that.  The original code grep'ed a file then piped the output to awk.  I sanitized the command, but didn't test it. :(